# Set new page access group to parent page access group

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, tsconfig

In TYPO3 it is possible to set the access group of new pages using TSConfig:

```
TCEMAIN {
    permissions.groupid = 1
}
```

However, we want to set it to the same group that's set for the parent page without having to manually set this TSConfig for all pages where it is changed. Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking for a similar solution in the past week, something like `groupId = inherit` would be great.

Can you open up a new issue for this? https://forge.typo3.org/projects/typo3cms-core/issues/new

Hopefully we can add this rather sooner than later (but not for v9 unfortunately), however I'm pretty sure this change could be built by an extension for v9, maybe one of my clients needs this as well at some point (hopefully rather sooner than later).

Comment: I'll open a new issue for this. This question was due to a wish from a client, so possibly they'd be willing to pay for an extension for 9. Shouldn't be too hard, just need to find the right hook or signal slot (processDatamapClass?)

Comment: The issue has been created: https://forge.typo3.org/issues/89917